# Variable move to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, beacon

Hi guys i need send this variable "minorBeacon" to another ViewController, how i can do ?

```
   func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion)


{
    if let beacon = beacons.first {
    var minorBeacon = beacon.minor.intValue

       print(minorBeacon)
       print(region)


    for beacon in beacons{
            if beacon.accuracy > 0{
        metrosBeacon.text = "El beacon identificado como  \(region.identifier) está en \(beacon.accuracy)m "

            if region.identifier == "MKT BEACON 28"{
                    linkBeacon.text = "Hace click acá para ver la oferta de MKT BEACON 28"
            if region.identifier == "MKT BEACON 26"{
                    linkBeacon.text = "Hace click acá para ver la oferta de MKT BEACON 26"

            if (beacon.accuracy) == -1.0{
        metrosBeacon.text = "❌Fuera de cobertura de señal de Beacons ❌"
        }
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to pass the information to a new view controller as you segue to it then you need to look into overriding the `prepareForSegue` method. If you want to make the value generally available throughout your app then have a look at `NSUserDefaults`. One or the other should suit your purpose.